# US Visa - change in travelling companions

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, borders

I’m travelling to Vegas in October. I had to get a Visa due to a previous arrest (which didn’t result in a conviction). Anyway, my visa was granted and I have it back. But now one person from our group has dropped out (due to personal reasons).

I remember when filling in the Ds-160 I had to list travelling companions, so I listed him and the other friends. Since he is no longer coming, does this affect my visa? Or if we replace him, will this affect my entry to the country

Answer (score 5):

No, it does not affect your visa. B1/2 visas are issued based on individual eligibility and not as a group.

Plans change. Visa and immigration officers know that. You can use your visa for an entirely different trip at an entirely different time as long as the purpose of that trip is allowed under your visa category. It is extremely unlikely that this would even come up at the Point of Entry. Even if it does it has no bearing on your eligibility as a non-immigrant.